# "Return map" for Brownian motion

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

Consider a Brownian motion $W$ reflected at the boundary of a domain $D$ in Euclidean space. I want to look at the process obtained by "restricting" it to the boundary.

I was thinking of taking the local time $L(t)$ at the boundary, and then defining my new process as $W(L^{-1}(t))$.

Is this the appropriate way to do it? Does it define a Markov process on the boundary? If so, what is known about this process for, say, a $d$-dimensional round ball (eg on its regularity/ size and frequency of jumps)?

Comment: You probably mean $W(L^{-1}(t))$ which would be a reasonable definition and would give you a Markov process on the boundary that locally looks like a Cauchy process. (In the case of $D$ a half-plane it would precisely be a Cauchy process.)

Comment: Thank you, that answers it. Fixed the error you mentioned.

Comment: This has been studied since 1960s, by Molchanov, Hsu, Kolsrud and others. If you like exact references, you may have a look at page 4 of my recent preprint at [arXiv:1912.00072](https://arxiv.org/abs/1912.00072).